# alternative download location for qt sdk

Tags: qt

is there an alternative to the [qt website](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads) for downloading the qt sdk ?

when trying to download the online installer for windows linked at http://qt.nokia.com/downloads, i get a `403 forbidden` error. submitting a bug report requires a tedious sign up process, i submitted a request through a contact form but i don't think any commercial department in the world care about a broken link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://get.qt.nokia.com/qtsdk/

This link lets you choose the SDK to download.  Hopefully they get that server fixed...It's been problematic for at least a week now.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question specifically mentions the SDK, but, in a pinch you could check out source from git and build. :p

http://qt.gitorious.org/

For what it's worth, I can't download it either. Either they're having some web server problems today or Balmer already put an agreeable bid!

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, [**from here**](http://www.developer.nokia.com/gen/latest_tools_sdks.rss):

[Qt SDK version 1.1.4  Online installer - 15 MB](http://nds2.fds-forum.nokia.com/p/d/fds_forum/23f71960-21d3-4b7a-9329-4d5484c49c68/Qt_SDK_Win_online/Qt_SDK_Win_online_1_1_4_en.exe?fdptoken=1325941134_024ec99d13357a7f57db67d7bf3a6367)

Comment: That's a 3 1/2 year ago post.

Answer (score 0):

Super old post.  Answering because I literally just had this a very similar issue, and ended up at this page by googling "qt 5.7 download error." For me, this issue was caused by a network time out when gathering repo meta data.

The solution as of 2017-01-21 is to use this [link](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2) because it has the normal online installer and the full (much bigger) offline installer.  I had to use the offline installer.